# Export scraped tables to CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrape

I´ve scraped these tables in one single table in python using BeautifulSoup. The code is the following :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(0,39):
    first=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/011/"+str(i)+".html").read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(first)
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
      tds = tr.find_all('td')
      print tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text
```

The result is something like this :

```
494560 ABAD SAAVEDRA, GERSON HORACIO 011 1116.8750
455314 ABAD VALVERDE, MARIA ISABEL 011 1482.7500
491005 ABREGU HUAMAN, MERCEDES LILIANA 011 503.4000
457929 ACOSTA ABAD, ALEJANDRO FRANCISCO 011 413.0500
```

So, how can I export this table to CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('listing.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(39):
        url = "http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/011/{}.html".format(i)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            html = u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:4]]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: A minor nitpick: It might be a little cleaner to UTF-8 everything at once instead of repeating yourself. Maybe `[elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:4]]`?

Comment: @abarnert, Thank you for advice. I update the code according to your comment.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial or topic to understand the code to export to CSV?

Comment: @CreamStat, If you follow the link in the answer, in the documentation, there's many examples.

Comment: @CreamStat: The module docs can look pretty scary, but if read the overview, then skip all the way down to [Examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples), you only need to use the middle part as a reference, when you already know what you're looking for (like what that `quoting` parameter really means).

Comment: What does 'UTF-8' means? How can I know that my table's code is 'UTF-8'?

Comment: @CreamStat, [`UTF-8`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF_8) is one of character encodings. You can use another encodings. I choose it because the webpage also used that. You can check the webpage encoding by inspecting HTTP header / `<meta>` tag in the HTML.